# Implementing a method that is also overriden

Tags: java, methods, extends, implements

I am adding `spring-security` into my app and came across an issue.  My implementation of `UserDetails` implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` but also extends my `User` entity class.  Both of these have a `getPassword()` method, the spring security interface's method returns a `String` and mine returns a byte array since the password is encrypted.

I want my implementation to implement the interface's method and not override my entity class' method but Netbeans keeps giving an error that the return type is invalid.  I would like to avoid renaming my `getPassword()` method to work around this problem.

Is there a way of telling the compiler to implement the interface's method instead of overriding the superclass?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return type is not taken into consideration when overloading, so essentially you can't really do that. I would simply rename my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, the return type can't be the only difference between two otherwise identical Java method signatures.

The easiest way to fix it is to declare `User` as a field instead of extending it:

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

  private final User user;

}
```

Comment: this might not be an Option at all, in case you *do* need to inherit all of `User` properties

Comment: i indeed need to inherit the user's properties.  I renamed my entity class' method to getEncryptedPassword since that's actually what it returns.  The compiler is happy now.